# Can Zipkin be used for console application

Tags: java, instrumentation, zipkin

Can be Zipkin used to instrument a console/classic application? I mean I have a method foo() and I want to know how much time it took.

Does Zipkin can be used just for applications that communicates over http protocol?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Zipkin generates traces and communicates them back to a Zipkin server. The latter action is typically performed via HTTP but Zipkin is agnostic to how a span is started and ended.

If you want to measure the execution time of a single method, you would normally create a local span that is nested inside a server span. Zipkin is a distributrd tracing tool for discovering machine-to-machine interaction which is why spans often cover HTTP. If you want to measure execution time of a method, a tool like metrics might be more suited.